# Get image from Fingerprint module

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, sensors

I want to get the image from the fingerprint module (https://makeradvisor.com/tools/fingerprint-sensor-module/) as a result of scanning. It is enough to have a single frame image. it would be good if the computer can get image the output image from the serial port (as in linescan camera example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=welv4w8B88g   https://www.tindie.com/products/ap_tech/tsl1401cl-linescan-camera/)

I am open to your suggestions if it can be done in another module.

Answer (score 2):

Since all of these cheap fingerprint readers are similar you can find a compatible datasheet and just find the commands and descriptions there. However, I couldn't find a datasheet that would include a good description of the protocol. So the other option is to look at the protocot through the software SFGDemo which is apparently capable of getting an image of a fingerprint. Or to use [this](https://pypi.org/project/fpscanner/) python package which apparently also can download the image.